# Delete using LINQ by joining two datatables

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, dataset

I have two datatable *DurationByCurrency*(inside a dataset) and *Fund* which looks like below
[image]

I want to delete the rows in *Duration By Currency* Datatable whose FundCode has value as 2 in *Fund* Dt by performing a join.

```
var result =  from table1  in raptorDS.Tables[RaptorTable.DurationByCurrency].AsEnumerable()
                               join table2  in fundDT.AsEnumerable()
                               on   table1.Field<string>("FundCode") equals table2.Field<string>("FundCode") into ps
                               from row in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                               {
                                    //delete query
                               }
```

Please help me on this as I am new to LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = from row1  in raptorDS.Tables[RaptorTable.DurationByCurrency].AsEnumerable()
                               join row2  in fundDT.AsEnumerable()
                               on   row1.Field<string>("FundCode") equals  row2.Field<string>("FundCode") 
                               where row1.Field<string>("value") 
                                    equals "2" select row1;

result.ToList().ForEach(row => row.Delete());
```

sample test code for linqpad:

```
void Main()
{
    //sample data for test 
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.Tables.Add(GetTable1());
    ds.Tables.Add(GetTable2());

    var result  = ( from rec1 in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
    join rec2  in ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable()
     on   rec1.Field<string>("FC") equals rec2.Field<string>("FC")
     where rec2.Field<int>("Value") == 2  select rec1);

     result.ToList().ForEach(row => row.Delete());
     //now you have only "ABCD" and "AZY" in table 1
     //ds.Tables[0].Dump(); linqpad display result
}

DataTable GetTable1()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("FC", typeof(string));
    table.Rows.Add("ABCD");
    table.Rows.Add("XYZ");
    table.Rows.Add("AZY");
    return table;
}

 DataTable GetTable2()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("FC", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));
    table.Rows.Add("ABCD", 1);
    table.Rows.Add("XYZ", 2);
    table.Rows.Add("AZY",3);
    return table;
}
```

Comment: in this line  where rec1.Field<string>("Type") , i am getting error "Cannot use local variable rec1 before it is declared. Do i need to declare rec1?